# ERROR [ExceptionHandler] Nest can't resolve dependencies of the MailAppService

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs

> iam trying to implement adapter pattern with sendgrid and nodemailer
> but i get this error : ERROR [ExceptionHandler] Nest can't resolve
> dependencies of the MailAppService (?). Please make sure that the
> argumen t Object at index [0] is available in the MailModule context.
>
> Potential solutions:
>
> - Is MailModule a valid NestJS module?
> - If Object is a provider, is it part of the current MailModule?
> - If Object is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within MailModule?   @Module({
>   imports: [ /* the Module containing Object */ ]   })

```js
export interface MailServiceInterface {
  sendWelcomeEmail(email: string, name: string): Promise<void>;

  sendAccountDeletionEmail(email: string, name: string): Promise<void>;
}
```

```js
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { MailServiceInterface } from '../interface/mail-service.interface';

@Injectable()
export class MailAppService {
  constructor(private readonly emailInterface: MailServiceInterface) {}

  async sendWelcomeEmail(email: string, name: string) {
    await this.emailInterface.sendWelcomeEmail(email, name);
  }

  async sendAccountDeletionEmail(email: string, name: string) {
    await this.emailInterface.sendAccountDeletionEmail(email, name);
  }
}
```

```js
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { MailerService } from '@nestjs-modules/mailer';
import { envConfigurations } from '../../../../env/env.configuration';

@Injectable()
export class NodemailerService {
  constructor(private readonly mailerService: MailerService) {}

  async sendWelcomeEmail(email: string, name: string) {
    await this.mailerService.sendMail({
      to: email,
      from: envConfigurations().mail.from,
      subject: 'Welcome to Unknown App',
      text: `Welcome to the app, ${name}. Let me know how you get along with the app.`,
      template: './templates/welcome',
      context: {
        name,
      },
    });
  }

  
}
```

```js
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { NodemailerService } from './nodemailer.service';
import { MailServiceInterface } from '../interface/mail-service.interface';

@Injectable()
export class NodemailerAdapterService implements MailServiceInterface {
  constructor(private readonly nodemailer: NodemailerService) {}

  async sendWelcomeEmail(email: string, name: string) {
    await this.nodemailer.sendWelcomeEmail(email, name);
  }

  async sendAccountDeletionEmail(email: string, name: string) {
    await this.nodemailer.sendAccountDeletionEmail(email, name);
  }
}
```

```js
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import * as SendGrid from '@sendgrid/mail';
import { envConfigurations } from '../../../../env/env.configuration';

@Injectable()
export class SendGridService {
  constructor() {
    SendGrid.setApiKey(envConfigurations().mail.sendGrid.apiKey);
    SendGrid.setSubstitutionWrappers('{{', '}}');
  }

  async send(mail: SendGrid.MailDataRequired) {
    return await SendGrid.send(mail);
  }

  async sendWelcomeEmail(email: string, name: string) {
    const mailData = {
      to: email,
      from: envConfigurations().mail.from,
      templateId: envConfigurations().mail.sendGrid.W_tempID,
      dynamic_template_data: {
        subject: 'Welcome to Unknown App',
        text: `Welcome to the app, ${name}. Let me know how you get along with the app.`,
      },
    };
    return await this.send(mailData);
  }


}
```

```js
 

   import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
    import { MailServiceInterface } from '../interface/mail-service.interface';
    import { SendGridService } from './sendGrid.service';

    @Injectable()
    export class SendGridAdapterService implements MailServiceInterface {
      constructor(private readonly sendGrid: SendGridService) {}

      async sendWelcomeEmail(email: string, name: string) {
        await this.sendGrid.sendWelcomeEmail(email, name);
      }

      async sendAccountDeletionEmail(email: string, name: string) {
        await this.sendGrid.sendAccountDeletionEmail(email, name);
      }
    }
```

```js
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { SendGridService } from './service/sendGrid.service';
import { MailerModule } from '@nestjs-modules/mailer';
import { envConfigurations } from '../../../env/env.configuration';
import { HandlebarsAdapter } from '@nestjs-modules/mailer/dist/adapters/handlebars.adapter';
import { MailAppService } from './service/mail.service';
import { NodemailerService } from './service/nodemailer.service';
import { NodemailerAdapterService } from './service/nodemailer-adapter.service';
import { SendGridAdapterService } from './service/sendGrid-adapter.service';

@Module({
  imports: [
    MailerModule.forRoot({
      transport: {
        host: envConfigurations().mail.nodemailer.host,
        port: envConfigurations().mail.nodemailer.port,
        secure: envConfigurations().mail.nodemailer.secure,
        service: envConfigurations().mail.nodemailer.service,
        auth: {
          user: envConfigurations().mail.nodemailer.auth.user,
          pass: envConfigurations().mail.nodemailer.auth.pass,
        },
      },
      defaults: {
        from: `"No Reply" - <${envConfigurations().mail.from}>`,
      },
      template: {
        dir: process.cwd() + '/src/modules/mail/templates/',
        adapter: new HandlebarsAdapter(),
        options: {
          strict: true,
        },
      },
    }),
  ],
  providers: [
    MailAppService,
    NodemailerService,
    NodemailerAdapterService,
    SendGridAdapterService,
    SendGridService,
  ],
  controllers: [],
  exports: [MailAppService],
})
export class MailModule {}
```

```js
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { UsersModule } from './modules/users/users.module';
import { AuthModule } from './modules/auth/auth.module';
import { DeletedUsersModule } from './modules/deleted-users/deleted-users.module';
import { MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { TokenModule } from './modules/token/token.module';
import { HashModule } from './modules/common/hash/hash.module';
import { ConfigModule } from '@nestjs/config';
import { envConfigurations } from '../env/env.configuration';
import { MailModule } from './modules/mail/mail.module';

@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      isGlobal: true,
      load: [envConfigurations],
      envFilePath: `${process.cwd()}/env/${process.env.NODE_ENV}.env`,
    }),
    MongooseModule.forRootAsync({
      useFactory: () => ({
        uri: envConfigurations().mongodb.MONGO_URI,
      }),
    }),
    UsersModule,
    AuthModule,
    DeletedUsersModule,
    TokenModule,
    HashModule,
    MailModule,
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: have you read this FAQ page: https://docs.nestjs.com/faq/common-errors#cannot-resolve-dependency-error ?

Comment: @MicaelLevi yes, the problem is 'MailAppService' when i remove it from the providers array and exports array every thing work but when i add it , gives me this error

Comment: so read that docs page again. It says that you can't use interface to inject, due to how typescript works.